# Twilio how to hear numbers in other language?

Tags: twilio

i have a menu, where user need to select 1 or 2. the prompt is an audio file where as the number is a twilio "Say".

```
<Play>http://example.com/russianaudio.wav</Play>
<Say voice="woman" language="ru">1</Say>
```

The problem is that after the audio file, instead of saying "один"(Russian for one), twilio is saying "one"(in English). Is there a way to get this working for Russian?
also will the below work?

```
 <Say voice="woman" language="ru">один</Say>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Evangelist here.

This should work fine, but you need to use the full two-part language code for [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say), as well as voice [`Alice`](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/07/twilio-tts-improvements.html):

```
<Say voice="alice" language="ru-RU">1</Say>
```

That should work for you.

Hope this helps,

Comment: thanks for the prompt response.
is it necessary to use "alice" instead of woman?

Comment: I've found it seems to work without, but you may find you get better results with Alice.